# Get code from rst file code-blocks

Tags: restructuredtext

What is the best and simplest way to parse ***.rst** file and get all code from `code-block`s to execute (or compile) this code? This may be useful to test some instructions in **.rst** format and use them for **CI** purposes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's actually easier to put the code examples into separate files and include them into the `.rst` file:

```
This is a code block from a file:

.. include:: file.php
   :code: php
```

See the [include directive's documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please specify, is it suitable for a situation when there are few code blocks in a single `.rst` file? Can a single code file be used in this case?

Comment: @Viktors this is just a literal include. You can include several different files in your `.rst` document or include one file several times.